# How to link LuaJIT with a C++ program?

Tags: c++, linker, luajit

I'm trying to simply use the following C++ code

```
lua_State *state = luaL_newstate();

luaL_openlibs(state);

lua_getglobal(state, "_G");
lua_pushstring(state, "print");
lua_pushnumber(state, 4.5);
lua_call(state, 2, 1);

lua_close(state);
```

And I'm getting linker errors.  All of the aforementioned function calls generate linker errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaL_newstate
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnumber
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_call
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushstring
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaL_openlibs
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_getfield
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_close
```

The header inclusion is done with this code :

```
extern "C" {
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
}
```

I "installed" LuaJIT using MinGW, mingw32-make BUILDMODE=static.  It gave me a nice "Successfully built LuaJIT".

I'm compiling the code with VS2012.  I've set up the linker like this :

Additional Library Directiories : D:\Programming\LuaJIT Source\LuaJIT-2.0.1\src
Additional Include Directiories : D:\Programming\LuaJIT Source\LuaJIT-2.0.1\src

I'm on a windows7 machine and I'm using the latest LuaJIT from their github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should compile all your libraries using the same compiler as your application. MinGW produces a .a library archive whereas MSVC typically outputs a .lib archive.

So: Recompile LuaJIT using MSVC, add the path where luajit.lib resides to your linker path and add luajit.lib to the list of libraries to be linked into your application.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I had to add this : #pragma comment(lib, "lua51.lib")

Comment: hi. i tryed to compile luajit using msvc as it says in installation instruction. but i always fail. i just can't start msvcbuild command from .net command prompt. does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the path to LuaJIT library ,see the pic below 
[image]